# Custom control in MAUI how it is processing?

Tags: custom-controls, maui

Imagine I have custom control - `ReqSinglPanel.xaml` with BindableProperty "CurrentRequest"

```
public partial class ReqSinglPanel : Grid
{
    public GetRquestsAndUser CurrentRequest
    {
        get => (GetRquestsAndUser)GetValue(CurrentRequestProperty);
        set { SetValue(CurrentRequestProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CurrentRequestProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(CurrentRequest),
        returnType: typeof(GetRquestsAndUser),
        declaringType: typeof(ReqSinglPanel),
        defaultValue: null,
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public ReqSinglPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //string img = CreateCntrImgSources(CurrentRequest.reqCurrIn);
    }
}
```

Now on my CorePage I'm binding object `TesOne` to this property

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Cntr:ReqSinglPanel HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        CurrentRequest="{Binding TestOne}"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Now, I want to do some work with my object INSIDE the `ReqSinglPanel`
First idea - ReqSinglPanel main constructor. Right?

```
public ReqSinglPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string img = CreateCntrImgSources(CurrentRequest.reqCurrIn);//just to test my assumption
    }
```

Well, no!
[image]

```
{System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

So what is the point of having property if I can't modify it inside my custom control to show it my way?
The only possible way that I've found to make any modifications is overriding some methods like
`OnSizeAllocated` or `OnPropertyChanged`.

Might I be missing something, could you explain how exactly custom control loading process goes and where I should catch my bound property to `torture` it?

Comment: Well, you have declared a writeable property and its basic nature is, that it can change at any time during the lifetime of the instance. If you want to keep your control in sync you have to implement that events

Comment: Ok. so you want to say - If the property is changed during the control lifetime it basically won't go through my "modifications" and it will break the logic? Well, I see the point, you are right. And under "Events" do you mean OnPropertyChanged method etc? Is it a good style to do modifications there? Or even might be in the "Get{} set{} " part of the property. For me, it looks a bit weird... I have a massive gap in my dev experience so in 2010 we did't do it this way normally))

Comment: You should never assume the value of a property has been set when the constructor runs

Comment: The `set` part of a property is where any extra logic goes. Almost always, a getter should just get a value from a "backing field". This keeps logic sane. Ideally, `set` is the only place that touches the "backing field". That BIndableProperty with GetValue/SetValue in property, is one way to do that. Somewhere else needs to manipulate the value? It gets the existing value, does its calculations, then sets the result. Done.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve. Basically, control just represents data with no recall to original source. That's why i don't care if the object would be changed during the control lifecycle. But for me using set() for extra logic still sounds a bit weird)) I recon Liqun Shen-MSFT solution should work. thank you man for your reaction)

Comment: Yes, BindableProperty.Create’s onChanged method is equally good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bindable properties from XAML haven't been set yet the constructor is called. So you get the default value which is set to be null. A similar issue on Github i have attached below. You could have a look.

As a workaround, define PropertyChanged event handler to [Detect property changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-7.0#detect-property-changes).

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CurrentRequestProperty =
BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: nameof(CurrentRequest),
    ...
    propertyChanged: OnIsPropertyChanged);

static void OnIsPropertyChanged (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
  // Property changed implementation goes here
  // could add the logic here
}
```

For more info, you could refer to
[Xamarin Forms Custom Control and Bindable properties not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838351/xamarin-forms-custom-control-and-bindable-properties-not-working-as-expected) and [Bindable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-7.0).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you. I was't sure the PropertyChanged event could be implemented for Custom controls. Will try.

Comment: I'm glad to help if you have any questions.